# WeifenLuo DockPanel Suite: embed into TabControl

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli, dockpanel

I am new to DockPanel Suite.
what i'm trying to achieve is, having Dockpanel component(with DocumentStyle = DockingMdi) within a TabControl in Winforms.
If i set DocumentStyle to DockingWindow or DockingSdi it works fine, but fewer docking options

```
SecondForm ^SF = gcnew SecondForm ();
SF->Show(dockPanel1, DockState::Document);
```

setting DocumentStyle to DockingMdi i get an runtime error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid parent form. When using DockingMdi or
>   SystemMdi document style, the DockPanel control must be the child
>   control of the main MDI container form.

i added `SF->Parent = this;` above SF->Show(), i get a new runtime error saying

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Top-level control cannot be added to a
>   control.

Comment: What is "mf"? The message of "the DockPanel control must be the child control of the main MDI container form" indicates that you should follow https://sourceforge.net/p/dockpanelsuite/discussion/402316/thread/43d232e4/ I am not sure what you want to achieve in the second query. Why do you want to call "dockpanel1.Hide"? That should only hide a control from its parent, and it definitely should not hide anything else like the floating windows.

Comment: @LexLi, sorry its SF not mf,
i followed the link you shared, above 'SF_>Show();'  i added SF->isMdiContainer=true;  for this i'm getting run time error "MDI container forms must be top-level".
I know this is a complex result that i'm trying to achieve. i also tried SF->Parent = TabControl1; for this runtime error is "Cannot add 'MyForm1' to TabControl.  Only TabPages can be directly added to TabControls"
For my 2nd query, i wanted to hide floating tabs when tabPage2 is clicked(as floating content was appearing in tabPage2 as well), achieved with 'DockContent->DockState = DockState::Hidden;'

Comment: You led yourself to a dead end, as when Microsoft designed MDI in WinForms such restrictions were set. DPS will not free you from them if you want to stick to MDI modes. In your case, since the form that holds dockPanel1 is not the top level form, you cannot use MDI simply.

Comment: Only ask one question at a time. I've edited the post to remove your second question, you should ask it separately.